# how to get a number between two characters?

Tags: regex

I have this string:

```
String values="[52,52,73,52],[23,32],[40]";
```

How to only get the number 40?

I'm trying this pattern `"\\[^[0-9]*$\\]"`, I've had no luck.

Can someone provide me with the appropriate pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your could update your pattern to use a capturing group and a quantifier `+` after the character class and omit the `^` anchor to assert the start of the string.

Change the anchor to assert the end of string `$` to the end of the pattern:

```
\\[([0-9]+)\\]$
   ^     ^^
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SDLZPo/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/mS7p2D)

For example:

```
String regex = "\\[([0-9]+)\\]$";
String string = "[52,52,73,52],[23,32],[40]";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
if(matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); // 40
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to use `^`

The correct regex here is `\\[([0-9]+)\\]$`

If you are sure of the single number inside the `[]`, this simple regex would do

`\\[(\d+)\\]`

Answer (score 1):

Given that you appear to be using Java, I recommend taking advantage of `String#split` here:

```
String values = "[52,52,73,52],[23,32],[40]";
String[] parts = values.split("(?<=\\]),(?=\\[)");
String[][] contents = new String[parts.length][];

for (int i=0; i < parts.length; ++i) {
    contents[i] = parts[i].replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "").split(",");
}

// now access any element at any position, e.g.
String forty = contents[2][0];
System.out.println(forty);
```

What the above snippet generates is a *jagged* 2D Java String array, where the first index corresponds to the array in the initial CSV, and the second index corresponds to the element inside that array.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `String.substring` if you need the content between the last `[` and last `]`:

```
String values = "[52,52,73,52],[23,32],[40]";       
String wanted = values.substring(values.lastIndexOf('[')+1, values.lastIndexOf(']'));
```

Comment: No my string could be something like this : "[522,52,73,52],[40],[2311,32],[40]"